# Regulating a negative output from a bridge rectifier

Tags: power

I've managed to get a regulated 5V output from my bridge rectifier using a linear regulator. I now need to use another linear regulator to regulate a -5V. I can't for the life of me find how I do this though.

Comment: Do you have a center tap?

Comment: Adam.... does the transformer have a centre tap?  this matters.  It can split the DC voltage or double the single ended voltage.  Otherwise you have to half-wave rectify

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 no it does not have a centre tap. I think I may swap to one to make it easier for me so I dont have to alter the rest of my circuit too much.

Comment: you can learn a lot by knowing how to model your supply. http://tinyurl.com/yyk2ga8o to choose the right configuration  with centre tap doubles the number of pulses per charge so without needs a much bigger cap to reduce the sag .  Any questions?

Answer (score 2):

Use a 7805 regulator for the positive side and a 7905 regulator for the negative side.

Here is an example circuit that shows this:

[image]
Source: https://www.twovolt.com/2016/08/22/5v-1a-dual-regulated-power-supply-using-7805-7905-ic/

Comment: Ok that makes sense, however I'm simming it with Multisim and I've had to ground the negative terminal or it doesn't work properly. With that ground I'm not sure this circuit works?

Comment: With any spice software, you have to pick a node as ground, it doesn't matter *which node is ground* the numbers *relative to one another* will be the same. If you ground the negative terminal, and float the supply, you'll get 10V on V+, 5V on ground and 0V on the negative terminal.

Comment: Since the OP asked for only -5V, every component in the +5 circuit above the common ground can be eliminated, and the + terminal on the bridge can be grounded.

Comment: Theres no galvanic isolation. Do you think it matters?

Comment: The 7805 and 7905 can't handle high voltage. For safety and to ensure you don''t burn up the regulators, use a step down transformer at minimum. You should also have galvanic isolation for safety reasons, to protect yourself and the circuit.